# How do you use: isalnum, isdigit, isupper to test each character of a string?

Tags: python, function, passwords, return

I am trying to make a password strength simulator which asks the user for a password and then gives back a score.

I am using:

```
islanum() 
isdigit()
isupper()
```

to try and see how good the inputted password is.

Instead of returning boolean values, I want this to assess each characters of the password, and then the program to add up all the "True" values and turn it into a score. EXAMPLE CODE:

```
def upper_case():
    points = int(0)
    limit = 3
    for each in pword:
        if each.isupper():
            points = points + 1
            return points
        else:
            return 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!! THANKS!!

Comment: Do you have any example code to show where you've started from or what you've tried so far?

Comment: You almost had this right. You just need to compute a score then return after the iteration (*not inside*).

Comment: Also ``points = int(0)`` is not necessary. ``points = 0`` is fine.

Comment: My knowledge of password strength theory isn't amazing but surely if all of your letters are uppercase it's just as weak as having them all lowercase? The idea behind your code is to give points to uppercase characters but I think you'd be better having a mixture. For example "password" and "PASSWORD" are equally as weak but "PAsSWorD" is stronger (or at least as strong as a password with the word "password" can be :P )

Comment: You probably want to rename ``upper_case()`` to ``get_score()`` and use some ``if/elif`` branching to calculate an appropriate score depending on the characters you see.

Comment: BTW: Your example `upper_case()` function will stop after processing the first character of `pword` because of the `return` statements inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

`.isalnum()`, `.isupper()`, `.isdigit()` and friends are methods of the `str` type in Python and are called like this:

```
>>> s = "aBc123"
>>> s[0].isalnum()
True
>>> s[1].isupper()
True
>>> s[3].isdigit()
True
```

**Simple `getscore()` Function:**

```
s = "aBc123@!xY"

def getscore(s):
    score = 0
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            score += 2
        elif c.isdigit():
            score += 2
        elif c.isalpha():
            score += 1
        else:
            score += 3
    return score

print getscore(s)
```

**Output:**

```
13
```

**Better Version:**

```
s = "aBc123@!xY"


def getscore(s):
    return len(s) + len([c for c in s if c.isdigit() or c.isupper() or not c.isalpha()])

print getscore(s)
```

**Output:**

```
17
```

Comment: Updated to give a higher score for anything non-alpha/digit/upper (*i.e: punctuation, spaces, etc*).

Comment: Pretty weird score function there. Most of the ones I've seen work based on length and variety; a 10-character password with uppercase, digits, and symbols in it scores higher than a 10-character password of all symbols. This scores more exotic characters higher no matter what.

Comment: It might be weird, but it matches what the OP was trying to do in the first place :) I agree though, just count the no. of upper/digit/punctuation characters -- DONE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
password = "SomePa$$wordYouWantToTest"
score = len([char for char in password if str(char).isupper() or str(char).isdigit() or not str(char).isalnum()])
```

This will count all upper chars, all digits and all non alphanumeric chars in `password` giving an integer

Output of the test:

```
>>>score
8
```

Comment: I like this approach, short and terse :) Taking advantage of *list comprehensions* :)

Comment: Strange score function you've written there. This just counts the number of characters that aren't lowercase letters; `BLASTHARDCHEESE` scores great, but `blasthardcheese` gets a 0.

Comment: sure because it has none of the given requirements. I woudn't do this. I even wouldn't check the passwords. Passwords like `123` are valid passwords too. But it does what the question asks

Comment: Why is every password valid? Because you can remember just a few really strong passwords. So it's valid to use "non" strong passwords (like 123456 or similar) on every page you have to register but don't really want to...

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of solving using regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
def password_strength(p):
    score = 0
    if re.search('\d+',p):
        score = score + 1
    if re.search('[a-z]',p) and re.search('[A-Z]',p):
        score = score + 1
    if re.search('[$#@!]', p):
        score = score + 1
    return score

print password_strength('Jac@kpasswor01')
```